# How can I specify Name for NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sharedpreferences, nsuserdefaults

I need to store "user_session" and "game_deck" related information in preferences.

At some point in my app, I need to clear all data stored in "game_deck", and at logout time, I need to clear all the data stored in "user_session".

I have achieved this functionality in android by specifying file name to preference.

```
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                        "user_session", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit();
```

and

```
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                        "game_deck", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit();
```

As I am creating same project for iPhone, how can I achieve same functionality in objective-C?

I need to use

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

for storing my data.But how can I specify two different defaults so that i can clear all variables from particular default file?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSUserDefault` works different from the `SharedPreference` in Android. Here there is a common `standardUserDefault` object, where you can save all your datas. There is no separate user default for say "user_session" and "game_deck".

What you can do is to create a dictionary

```
NSMutableDictionary *userSessionDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[userSessionDict setObject:@"someUsername"  forKey:@"username"];


NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[default setObject:userSessionDict forKey:@"user_session"];

//you can remove using
[default removeObjectForKey:@"user_session"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably just store two children on the "root" level instead of maintaining two separate hierarchies. Just get and store them using the get/set `NSDictionary` methods. For example, to get your "user_session" preferences, you'd use this:

```
NSDictionary user_session = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"user_session"];
```

Likewise, you could clear this using:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDictionary dictionary] forKey:@"user_session"];
```

You'd just have to make sure that you initialize the dictionaries at launch if they don't yet exist.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that follow this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:Context.MODE_PRIVATE forKey:@"user_session"];
[defaults setObject:Context.MODE_PRIVATE forKey:@"game_deck"];
```

when you want to clear all variables from particular:(use "user_session" for e.g. ) :

```
[defaults removeObjectForKey:@"user_session"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: This remove all objects that you have stored in userDefaults, in your application.

```
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```